# Modelo de base de datos con Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Quisiera saber si es posible implementar un documento que tenga como atributo un array de documentos y como hacerlo.
Por ejemplo:

```html
Usuario = {
  nombre: String,
  archivo: [{
    ruta: String
  }]
}
```

Comment: intentaste hacerlo? Te lo pregunto porque el ejemplo que pones desde ya debiera funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos formas en la que un documento puede tener un array de documentos:

1. Subdocumentos
2. Documentos de referencia

---

**Subdocumentos**

Un documento puede tener subdocumentos como cualquier otro campo. Tomando como base tu ejemplo:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  nombre: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  archivos: [{
    ruta: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }]
});
```

En el ejemplo anterior un documento puede tener dentro de `archivos` muchos documentos. Para consultar es muy sencillo:

```
User
  .findById(id)
  .then(user => {
     console.log(user.archivos); // [ { ruta: '/tmp/amvf3vc.pdf' } ]
  });
```

**Documentos de referencia**

Los documentos de referencia son solamente `_id`s que **hacen referencia** a otros documentos que incluso pueden estar en otra colección. Esto es muy parecido a las clásicas *relaciones* en SQL.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  nombre: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  archivos: [{
    ruta: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'Archivo',
      required: true
    }
  }]
});
```

En este caso en particular, `Archivo` es otra colección:

```
const ArchivoSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  weight: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  createAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.Now
  }
});
```

Cuando se crea un documento `User` y se le agregan `Archivos`, el campo `archivos` tendrá los identificadores de los documentos `Archivo` asociados a dicho usuario:

```
archivos: [
  '',
  '',
  ''
]
```

Para consultar es un poco diferente. Si consultamos como en el ejemplo anterior, obtendrías el documento con el campo archivos como tal, pero sin los documentos a los que hacen referencia. En este caso, necesitamos **poblar** el documento principal con los subdocumentos a los cuales hace referencia.

```
User
  .findById(id)
  .then(user => {
     let _user = user;
     delete _user.archivos;

     user.archivos.forEach(arch => {
       Archivo.findById(arch).then(doc => {
         _user.push(doc);
       });
     });

     resolve(_user);
  });
```

Afortunadamente, ODMs como Mongoose en Node.js hacen eso por ti:

```
User.findById(id).populate('archivos');
```

---

> ¿Cuándo usar subdocumentos vs referencias?

Si tiene sentido poner una colección aparte, entonces conviene usar referencias. Por ejemplo, si tienes una colección que puede ser utilizada para otras cosas aparte de su relación con otra, utiliza referencias. Por otro lado, si tu colección aparte solo sirve para un pequeño y único objetivo que depente de otra colección, usala como subdocumento.

Answer (score 0):

Claro que es posible. Te recomiendo utilizar el paquete Mongoose, que hace más fácil crear esquemas NoSQL al igual que manejar dichos modelos con métodos bastante útiles.

Más información aquí. http://mongoosejs.com/

Un ejemplo:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    email: {type: String},
    password: {type: String},
    firstname: {type: String},
    lastname: {type: String},


}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```